# Why is my farmer just staring at the floor?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a farmer in an auto wheat farm who is not tending the farm. It is fully planted and he was previously farming it, but now he is just sitting on an edge looking at the floor.

I have lit up any ravines in the direction he is staring and surrounding him and he wont stop doing it and get back to farming.

What could be this dudes issue?

Comment: Full inventory maybe? Does he have a villager buddy to throw stuff at? What happens when you throw farmable stuff at him?

Comment: Can you post some screen shots?

Answer (score 2):

My own villagers did this once until I realized they couldn't reach the other nearby crops and farmland, They just stopped farming all together.

I changed all the nearby tilled soil and allowed access to all the current farmland and they started working again, You could try that.